# CSS Positioning - sections of the page overlapping

Tags: html, css, positioning

I have a quick question about CSS positioning. I have already looked up all about absolute, relative, static etc but am still having problems. So, for example, on one of my webpages, I am using four different div's for the four seperate sections I have on the page. I can manage to position them so they look perfect, but the top left section expands as the user adds entrys. When it expands, it then overlaps the section below it. Same with the other side, the section expands a little if it needs to display error messages and overlaps the section below it. Any suggestions as to how I would overcome this?

Thank you !!

Comment: please provide some source so we can see what you have

Comment: Could you please show us some code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want divs to flow normally on a page, you don't have to use positioning. Generally, if you are using positioning, you use it for a div that you want to have in a specific place that would in a normal situation, be somewhere else. For example: you would position something relatively if you wanted it to actually escape the container it is in. You would position something absolutely if you want it to be in exactly the same place, no matter what (this includes scrolling) OR if you want to overlap divs using a z-index.

Usually, if you just want divs to line up side by side, you can display: inline or use float.

Comment: Thank you, as it turned out I was just making things more complicated for myself, by using float I was able to resolve the problem.